# Confusion between eigen value decomposition and singular value decomposition

Tags: matrices

The Singular Value Decomposition of matrix $H$ gives
$$H = U \Sigma V^H$$

The Eigen value decomposition of  $$HH^H= U \Sigma \Sigma^t U^H$$

I took an example in matlab and performed EID and SVD respectively

```
H= [0.1, 0.3, .4; 0.5 , 0.5, 0.9; 0.1, 0.4, 0.5]
[U,e]= eigs(H*(conj(transpose(H))))
[U,D,Vh]= svd(H)

H =

    0.1000    0.3000    0.4000
    0.5000    0.5000    0.9000
    0.1000    0.4000    0.5000


U =

    0.3598    0.4271   -0.8295
    0.8160   -0.5751    0.0578
    0.4524    0.6977    0.5555


e =

    1.9450         0         0
         0    0.0450         0
         0         0    0.0000


U =

   -0.3598    0.4271   -0.8295
   -0.8160   -0.5751    0.0578
   -0.4524    0.6977    0.5555


D =

    1.3946         0         0
         0    0.2121         0
         0         0    0.0034


Vh =

   -0.3508   -0.8256    0.4419
   -0.4997    0.5641    0.6573
   -0.7920    0.0097   -0.6105
```

1) As a sanity check if I square the singular values of $H$ obtained from SVD, I obtain the eigen values of $HH^H$ obtained from the EID. We need to square the elements in D to obtain e...

BUT

2) But, shouldn't the matrix U from the SVD be equal to the matrix U from the eigen value decomposition  ??? MATLAB is not giving me that as you can see above.. In particular the first columns of U matrix dont match.

If any more details or explanation is needed I can provide. Looking forward for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\lambda$ is an eigenvalue of $A$ with multiplicity $1$, then there exist two real vectors with norm $1$ which satisfy $Ax=\lambda x$. This is because you can always multiply $x$ with $-1$, which does not change its norm.

Comment: so the above U matrices are correct? is my intuiton correct should they be equal althought one is from EID and the other from SVD

Comment: @Henry No, they can be different. $U$ contains the eigenvectors, and it can contain either $x$ or $-x$. Both are correct

Comment: thank you very much. can i say that both U and V from the SVD contain the eigen vector or just U? @5xum

Comment: if i rephrase my question. i mean in general when we perform svd does it give us the matrices of eigen vector or singular vectors?

Comment: One contains left eigenvectors of $HH^H$ vectors and one contains right ones..